# $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a^n+1}$ with $a \ge 0$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I'm  a bit rusty with limits
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a^n+1}$$ with $a \ge 0$.

The solution in my book is $max \left \{ 0,1 \right \}$ but
my final results are:

1)  $+\infty$ if $0<a<1$

2)  $1$ if $a>1$

3)  $+\infty$ if $a=1$

Comment: Note that $\max\{0,1\} = 1$ -- presumably you meant something else?

Comment: hint: $$\sqrt[n]{a^n+1}=e^{\frac{log(a^n+1)}{n}}$$

Comment: Yes because $$ \sqrt[n]{a^n+1}=(a^n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ and $a^b=e^{b\log(a)}$ (with conditions). If $0<a<1$ then $a^n\to 0$ use $\log(1+h)$ with $h$ small, if $a>1$ use $(a^n+1)=a^n(1+\frac{1}{a^n})$. The case $a=1$ is straightforward.

Comment: if $|a|<1$ then $\frac1n\ln(1+a^n)=\sum_{k\ge 1}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{a^{nk}}{nk}$

Comment: If $a\ge1$ lim = $a$ and  if $a\le 1$ lim =$1$ so answer is $max\{a, 1\}$ all these limits are straight forward.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery, I'm guessing the $0$ in $\max\{0,1\}$ is supposed to be an $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $0<a<1:$

$1 \lt (a^n +1)^{1/n} \lt (2)^{1/n} .$

$1\le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a^n+1)^{1/n} \le $

$\lim_{ n\rightarrow \infty }2^{1/n} =1.$

2) $a>1:$

$a \lt (a^n +1)^{1/n} \lt (2a^n)^{1/n}.$

$a \le \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty}(a^n+1)^{1/n} \le $

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(2)^{1/n}a = a.$

3)$a=1. $

Can you do it?

Comment: I'm not used to the bernoully 's inequality ...lim_n a^n=0 , does  (a^n+1)^{1/n} should be 1^{1/n}

Comment: Anne. y= x^1/n is strictly increasing: means: x <y, then x^1/n < y^1/n. First line:: 1<a^n+1<(1+1) since a^n <1; now take the n-th root. The case a>1 :  a^n <a^n +1 < 2a^n, since a^n>1. Now take  the root. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 4):

The correct result is $\max\{a, 1\}$, so I suppose it's a typo or a miscopied expression. To see this, note that

- If $a \le 1$, then $1 \le a^n + 1 \le 2$ for all $n$. Taking $n$-th roots and a limit gives limit $1$.
- If $a > 1$, then
  $$\left(a^n + 1\right)^{1/n} = a \left(1 + \frac{1}{a^n}\right)^{1/n}$$
  Now apply the previous case with $1/a$ to see why this tends to $a \cdot 1 = a$.

---

The key idea here is that if $a < 1$, the term $a^n$ is negligible once $n$ is large. If $a > 1$, the term $1$ is negligible once $n$ is large.

Answer (score 3):

1. By [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)$, 1 \le (1+a^n)^{1/n}\leq 1+\frac{a^n}{n} \to 1$ and so the limit is $1$ if $0 \le a < 1$.
2. If $a>1$, then $a \le \sqrt[n]{a^n+1} \le \sqrt[n]{a^n+a^n} = a \sqrt[n]{2} \to a$ and so the limit is $a$.
3. If $a=1$, then $\sqrt[n]{a^n+1}=\sqrt[n]{2} \to 1$.

You don't really need case 3 because the other two cases work for $a=1$.

Therefore,
$\displaystyle
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a^n+1} = \max(a,1)
$.

Comment: and for $a>1$ $lim_{n->\infty}(a^n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}=a$.

Comment: In 2: $\sqrt[n]{a^n+1}=\sqrt[n]{a^n}\sqrt[n]{(1+a^{-n})}\to a$,  no need to inequality

Answer (score 1):

I agree with
$\sqrt[n]{a^n+1}=e^{log\sqrt[n]{a^n+1} }=e^{\frac{log(a^n+1)}{n} }$

If $a>1$  $\frac{log(a^n+1)}{n}<\frac{log(a^n)}{n}=\frac{n*log(a)}{n}=log(a)$ and then $lim_n \sqrt[n]{a^n+1}=e^{log {a}}=a$

If $0<a<1$  $\frac{log(a^n+1)}{n}<\frac{log(a^n)}{n}=\frac{n*log(a)}{n}=log(a)$ and then $lim_n \sqrt[n]{a^n+1}=e^{log {a}}=a$   (but $a<1$!!!)

If $a=1$ ,   $\sqrt[n]{a^n+1}=\sqrt[n]{1^n+1} $and then  $lim_n \sqrt[n]{1^n+1}=lim_n \sqrt[n]{2}=1$

If $a=0$ ,   $\sqrt[n]{a^n+1}=\sqrt[n]{1} $  and then  $lim_n \sqrt[n]{1}=1$

I'm not sure about the case of $0<a<1$ because a <1 and the result is not the maximum between a and 1.